# Kernel Streaming User Mode driver

Tags: c++, c, windows, audio-streaming

I want to write a Kernel Streaming driver (that operates in user mode). I've been doing some research and it looks like for USB devices I'll want to use AVStream and for other devices I'll use Portcls. I can communicate with AVStream (I think) through some of the functionality defined in the KSProxy. However, I have not found a way to communicate with Portcls. Can anybody offer some insight?

Also I don't know a whole lot about Kernel Streaming. I just know what I have researched so any advice would be helpful.

The first functionality I want to implement is device management. I want to be able to manage devices (ex. get devices properties and take control of devices). I'm not sure of the best way to do this. Also, I want to be able to choose which device I use for audio streaming.

Also eventually I want to be able to support playback and recording but I'm sure by the time I'm ready to implement that I will know the path to take.